# Custom aspx based data entry form and nintex workflow

Tags: workflow

I am building a workflow in which user initiates a request by submitting a form. Once submitted my approver workflow starts and control goes to 1st approver. Now if there is any mistake in form data i want approver to write "Correction" in lazy approval email and control should go back to user for corrections..resubmit the form and control goes back to approver. My question is how to send control back to the initiator for correction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this.

1. In workflow, create a keyword called "Correction" and map it to reject. create a loop and branch on reject, which points to initiator. so when apprrover do a correction in lazy approval email, will create task/email for initiator to do changes. use can use Assignflexitask we can change the keyword name there.
2. Another way is to using form only, create a section with button approve, reject, correction this section will only visible to approver. so based on button click you can proceed with your requirement and lazy approval email will contain form link so user have to come to portal also however you can have one field in the list having show you currently the control is at : Initiator, aooprover1, and so on.. so you have to update that field on button click, use of this having will be to create a view accordingly.

Comment: Anuja thanks for the update. I did this already long time back by myself and checked this question today. I opted approach # 1 which you suggested.